# Difference between clients Date.now()

Tags: javascript, timer, timestamp

I want to display the same timer values to all users. When server start timer, he send to clients countdown finish date.
`clients.broadcast({ timerFinish: Date.now() + 5000 })` *server* generates finish time and give it to clients;

 `timeLeft = serverData.timerFinish - Date.now()` *clients* do calculation every second to get time until timer finish;

But clients got different `Date.now()` value! Also server have difference.
 **How to realise this timer better?**

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, in this sort of situation, the server's clock wins any disputes.

In that case, send the server's time to the clients as well:

```
const now = Date.now();
clients.broadcast({ now, timerFinish: now + 5000 });
```

Then the clients can calculate the difference between the server's time and their time and use that information.

That doesn't allow for transmission time, but in most cases it'll be "good enough." If you need to allow for transmission time, you'll need multiple round-trips between the client and server for them to determine a statistical mean of the network time (which may be incorrect for any individual exchange as these things vary, but there's only so much you can do).

To get **really** accurate about it, you could look into how the Network Time Protocol (NTP) works and emulate that a bit.

Comment: Well, I need to know websocket latency. Is it good practice to send ping messages from clients to server every 10 seconds and calculate latency?

Comment: @car1ot - I'm afraid that's not something I have expertise with. I'd think you rmobile clients might complain about data usage, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a stateful server that maintains the same counter for all connected clients, then why not count down once on the server and send the resulting value to all clients. This will also eliminate any lag some clients may have.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because it takes time to send the message to each client, so the final time will be later for each client depending on the speed of it being sent from the server.

Are you certain that `serverData.timerFinish` is different for each user, or is it only the final calculation `serverData.timerFinish - Date.now()` that is differnet for the start?

Anyways, to solve the discrepancy, and to test it, try simply sending Date.now() from the server to each client, and see if they get the same value from the server (they should).

The problem I believe is when its later being mixed with the client's `Date.now`, so you need to calculate the amount of time that was taken from broadcast to receiving, so when you receive it in the client side, simply set it (right away, before the other time) to `(Date.now() - (timerFinish - 5000)) + 5000` (or better yet just send Date.now() from server and add 5000 later), to fix the discrepancy.